# Proving $\frac{{n-d\choose g}}{{n\choose g}}\geq\frac{1}{2}$ when $g\ll n-d$ and $d\ll n$.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

How do I show that $\frac{{n-d\choose g}}{{n\choose g}}\geq\frac{1}{2}$ when $g=o(n-d)$ and $d=o(n)$. I can see this intuitively using examples but struggle to show this rigorously due to the binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{{n-d\choose g}}{{n\choose g}}
\geq\frac{1}{2}$
 when $g=o(n-d)$ and $d=o(n)$

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{{n-d\choose g}}{{n\choose g}}
&=\dfrac{\frac{(n-d)!}{g!(n-d-g)!}}{\frac{n!}{g!(n-g)!}}\\
&=\dfrac{(n-d)!(n-g)!}{(n-d-g)!n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(n-d)!(n-g)!}{n!(n-d-g)!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{d-1}(n-g-k)}{\prod_{k=0}^{d-1}(n-k)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{d-1}(1-(g-k)/n)}{\prod_{k=0}^{d-1}(1-k/n)}\\
&\approx\dfrac{1-\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}(g-k)/n)}{1-\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}k/n}
\qquad\text{If } d = o(\sqrt{n})\\
&=\dfrac{1-\frac1{n}(dg-d(d-1)/2)}{1-\frac1{n}d(d-1)/2)}\\
&=\dfrac{n-d(g-(d-1)/2)}{n-d(d-1)/2}\\
&=\dfrac{n-dg+d(d-1)/2}{n-d(d-1)/2}\\
&=\dfrac{n-d(d-1)/2-dg+d(d-1)}{n-d(d-1)/2}\\
&=1+\dfrac{-dg+d(d-1)}{n-d(d-1)/2}\\
&\approx 1
\qquad\text{If } d, g = o(\sqrt{n})\\
\end{array}
$

This is a start.
Better estimates will probably
produce a better result.